# Object retain count

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, retaincount

I allocated an object like this:

```
PixelInfo *ob1=[[PixelInfo alloc]initWithName:clr :t];
```

Then the retaincount of object is 1.

Then I did like this....

```
[faceColor addObject:ob1];
```

Then the retain count increased to 2. Why?

```
for(b=xi[i];b<=(xi[i+1]+1);b++)
        {   


            CGPoint t;
            t.x=b;
            t.y=y;

            UIColor *clr=nil;
            clr=[self getPixelColorAtLocation:loadImage.CGImage :t];    

             PixelInfo *ob=[[PixelInfo alloc]initWithName:clr :t];                    
             [faceColor addObject:ob];
             [ob release];
          }
```

This is my code .Even after releasing the object ob,Memory leakage happens.Why?

Comment: related to -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804291/leaks-while-adding-to-array-in-while-loop

Answer (score 1):

All colllections (Array, Dictionary, Set) increase object's retain count  when you doing 
`[smth addObject: obj]`.

PS. AddSubview also increase retain count of subview

Comment: and whenever a release message is sent to array then release message is automatically sent to all its objects.

Answer (score 0):

In below statement,you have alloced the object then retain count will be increased by 1 that's why you are getting is 1.

```
PixelInfo *ob1=[[PixelInfo alloc]initWithName:clr :t];
```

In next statement,I consider faceColor is an `NSMutableArray`

```
[faceColor addObject:ob1];
```

You are adding the object **ob1** in an array, So iOS will increase the retain count of any object by 1 if you add that in an Array,

That's the reason,You have retain count 2.

**EDITED:**

Here is what apple says.

> **Important:** This method is typically of no value in debugging memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method.

Comment: After adding to array i want to release that object.For that i did like this [ob1 release]; But its retain count will goes to 1 then that object will not get released right?

Comment: Right: it will be dealloc'd as soon as you remove it from the array too (or you release the whole array). This is normal behaviour, you create an object, add to the array and then you release it. You do this because you are responsible of memory management of the object, so you create and then you release the object, but the NSArray must retain it in order to maintain its internal consistency.

Comment: Don't think of retain counts as absolute numbers.  That it is 1 after the alloc/init is an implementation detail of `PixelInfo`.  It could be 5 or 10, it doesn't matter.  Think of it as a delta.  For everytime you cause it to increase, you must cause it to decrease if the object is ever to be deallocated.

Comment: @bbum : yes agree what you said,but the above question was very stright forward to explain, the object created by us,may be retained by iOS and retainCount could go up 5 or more,

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  In teaching many new developers, I find any notion that an absolute retain count is somehow valid to cost the developer hours of un-learning frustration when faced with their first real world memory management issues.

Comment: How can i release this object then?I am doing the above code within a loop.After executing it for a number of times, the application crashes That is my issue.....

Comment: @Priya : After observing you code releasing ob does'nt seems me the reason of crashing ...I realyy could not get the need of using  NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:5]; statement, you could directly add you object to faceColor, alos advice you accept some of answer yo get the better answer quickly.

Comment: Please check the code now...Also after for a number of times it crashing.I debugged the application and i understood it is crashing from that point and giving me an error like: malloc: *** error for object 0x5030200: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
I dont know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `faceColor` is an NSMutableArray. When you add an object to a container like NSArray or NSDictionary, the container retains the added object. That's because the container now relies on the added object to continue to exist as long as it is inside the container.